# Next middleware fetching data multiple times

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am using middleware concept in Nextjs to fetch data from my backend, but I am getting the same multiple times of request in console.log of terminal. How can I make one request to backend server only ?

Here my code in middleware.js:

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';

const PUBLIC_FILE = /\.(.*)$/;

export async function middleware(req, event) {
    const { pathname, locale, search } = req.nextUrl;

    fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/auth')
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((json) => console.log(json)); // prints multiple data in terminal

    if (pathname.startsWith('/_next') || pathname.includes('/api/') || PUBLIC_FILE.test(pathname)) {
        return;
    }

    if (locale === 'default') {
        const locale = req.cookies.get('NEXT_LOCALE') || 'en';

        return NextResponse.redirect(new URL(`/${locale}${pathname}${search}`, req.url));
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it running on every request (like maybe including your favicon)? If so, setting a matcher in an exported config would fix that.

Comment: No, the favicon file was excluded in PUBLIC_FILE in my above code

Comment: can you write the `fetch` after  `if (pathname.startsWith('/_next') || pathname.includes('/api/') || PUBLIC_FILE.test(pathname)) {
        return;
    }`

Comment: @Epple your fetch is happening before that early return. And Next also has [config just for that purpose](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/middleware#matcher).

Comment: You need to either move your if statement before the fetch, as @Yilmaz said, or use the `matcher` object like @ZacAnger suggested. Also, you may wanna use `async`/`await` instead of `.then` if you want to fetch data before your middleware finishes executing. And if you want to understand why there are multiple requests in the first place, check the linked thread's answer please.